# Air density at very high altitudes ( $h > 100 km $)

Tags: thermodynamics, atmospheric-science, drag, density, air

The temperature gradient model works very well for altitudes as high as a few kilometers above sea level.
However such a model is obviously wrong at high altitudes as temperature starts to rise rather than decrease.
Given that the gaz molecules are so far apart at such high altitudes, temperature is not even well defined in the usual sense, and using the ideal gaz law seems far fetched to me.
I've done some research but I couldn't find a convincing answer regarding this issue, so what is the usual model when dealing with such high altitudes?
I'm trying to evaluate the approximate time necessary for reentry in Low Earth Orbit, so I'm not in dire need for precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However such a model is obviously wrong at high altitudes as temperature starts to rise rather than decrease.

This is what all the very high altitude models do simply because it's what the atmosphere does.  The region you are talking about starts at the [Thermosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermosphere). The name is due to the fact that the temperature does indeed *rise* here.  This layer goes up to the Exosphere, about the $480\,km$ mark.

A model of interest to you might be the one described in this document from NASA called the [Marshall Engineering Thermosphere model MET-2007](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170005172/downloads/20170005172.pdf).  This document has a lot of formulas.  As with most models of this level of sophistication they are not simple formulas and include dirurnal and seasonal effects.

What would (probably) be used in practice in an empirical model called the [Jacchia Reference Atmosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacchia_Reference_Atmosphere).  I cannot tell you anything about this in detail that Wikipedia does not, but you asked for a formula and that model is empirical, so not really what you want.  [Web Archive has a page of links to models](https://web.archive.org/web/20060511235337/http://modelweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/atmos/atmos_index.html) you can search for.  Most of these models are likely in the form of Fortan code or tables.

These models are hard to find online and one that might be suitable is the beautifully named [MSIS Model 1986](https://web.archive.org/web/20060512024637/http://modelweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/atmos/msis.html) which is (apparently) the same as the COSPAR International Reference Model.  This model is designed specifically for abouve $100\,km$.

A very quick search on the web reveals what NASA refer to as the [Earth Atmosphere model](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/atmosmet.html), which I'll briefly state the formula for.  NASA use (sensibly :-) ) metric units for this and they don't give a source or derivation for the constants they use.  So meters, celsius, kilo-pascals, kg per meter cubed are the units.

In all cases they use density :

$$\sigma = \frac {P}{0.2689(T+273.1)}$$

**The Troposhere ( ground to about $11\, km$ ).**

$$T = 15-04 - 0.00649h$$
$$P = 101.29 \left( \frac{T+273.1}{288.08} \right)$$

**The Lower Stratosphere ( about 11km to about 25km ).**

$$T = -56.46$$
$$P = 127.76\,\exp(-0.000157h)$$

**The Upper Stratosphere ( about 25km and beyond ).**

$$T = -131.21 + 0.00299h$$
$$P = 2.488 \left(\frac{T+273.1}{216.6}\right)^{-11.288}$$